# Windows 7 / Graphics Card sporadically recognizes LCD TV connected via HDMI

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, lcd, tv

I have an issue with my PC/Graphics Card not always recognizing my LCD TV as a TV.  It will sometimes after a reboot or wake after sleep mode only recognize it as a generic display which severely limits the display capabilities and does not allow for audio over hdmi.  I'm not sure if this is a windows issue or a graphics card issue.  I have confirmed that my graphics card as well does not recognize the TV and treats it as a generic display at the same time.

My current work around is to unplug the hdmi connection and plug it into another input on the TV then changing to the new input.  The PC and Graphics card will then recognize the TV, but then I have to readjust the video settings and confirm the audio settings.  I'd rather not have to do this at all.  Has anyone encountered something similar to this?

Thanks,

PC/TV Details:

- LG LCD TV
- Windows 7
- Nvidia Geforce GTX 260 - latest drivers as of 1/27/2014
- DVI to HDMI adapter
- 6 ft HDMI cable
- bios is configured to use PCIe-x16 (my graphics card) for display (no onboard options)

Update -
I've updated the driver for my graphics card it was a few months old.  Issue still occurs.  I've turned on rigorous monitor detection and enable tv detection in the startup settings for the graphics card.  I've noticed now when I reboot the login screen for Windows 7 will use my TV as primary like it should, but soon as I login the tv goes blank and I have to repeat disconnecting and reconnecting the HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your graphics drivers are up to date, it could also be the adapter causing the issue. If your graphics card doesn't have a native HDMI port, it may not support what you need.

Comment: I have the latest drivers, and i don't think it could be the adapter since is a digital dvi to hdmi.  The adapter works because i can get it to work when i disconnect and reconnect the hdmi cable to the tv.